# Is there a known way to pass variables from django views to a js scipt on a template? I am building a chart, and need to display information

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, django, view

So, I would want to pass a variable into NEED_VARIABLE_PASSED. This code is in one of my html templates. I understand I can't use {{variable}}, so is there a way?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
               function drawChart() {
               var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" }],
                    ["WLWS", NEED_VARIABLE_PASSED, "#696969"],
                    ["Upperbin", NEED_VARIABLE_PASSED, "#696969"],
                    ["Solenoid", NEED_VARIABLE_PASSED, "#696969"],
                    ["BrakeSW", NEED_VARIABLE_PASSED, "color: #696969"]
               ]);
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `json_script` template tag to safely get the variable into JS, see the Django documentation here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script